# Вопрос про VLAN

Tags: dhcp

Делаю тут курсач - нужно сеть построить. Условия такие - есть здание. 5 этажей. на этажах торчат шнурки UTP 3. На каждом этаже по два отдела. У отделов есть коммутаторы на 24 порта. Один из отделов расположен территориально на верхнем и нижнем этажах здания в разных (противоположных) углах. Нужно построить сеть с выходом в инет.
Хочу сделать так. Чтобы всё было красиво по ip-адресам, делаю VLAN (Хочется чтобы у одного отдела были ip 192.168.0.1-255, у второго 192.168.1.1-255, у третьего 192.168.2.1-255 и т.д.). Это хочу сделать через управляемый коммутатор, расположенный типа в подвале, от которого идут шнурки UTP 3 по этажам. Отдел, который разделен внести в сеть VLAN1 (просто назначить два порта разныех как VLAN1), остальные VLAN2, VLAN3 и и т.д. каждый на своем порте.
Вопрос номер раз - насколько целесообразно так делать? То есть насколько распространена технология VLAN сейчас,нужно ли так VLANом делать?
Вопрос номер два - каким образом в данном случае можно поднять DHCP? То есть если я на коммутаторе укажу там первому порту подсеть 192.168.0.1/24, второму 192.168.1.1/24, третьему 192.168.2.1/24 и т.д., то потом при присоединении компа в определенном отделе чтобы он именно "свой" ip получил со своей подсетью, как нужно поступить? Если я сделаю ДО коммутатора сервер DHCP, то после коммутатора будут ip правильно все раздаваться, или у коммутатора сразу есть возможность поднять DHCP?

Или вообще VLAN сделать только к отделу который разделен по этажам, а остальным на этажах поставить DHCP серверы? Но тогда друг друга подсети видеть не будут, ведь так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно взять свич level3 , можно поставить перед свитчем маршрутизатор и на нем прописать примерно следующее:vlan2 192.168.0.1/24vlan3 192.168.1.1/24vlan4 192.168.2.1/24 Можно также настроить dhcp с указанием на какой влан какие айпишники выдавать.Далее создаете на свитче vlan2, vlan3, vlan4  и настраиваете согласно портам. Если у вас больше не будет управляемых свитчей, делаете порты untag.

Comment: Спасибо, в общем-то сам разобрался уже с этим:)

Answer (score 1):

Типа в подвале настраиваете vlan'ны. vlan1 использовать нельзя, по умолчанию в не настроенном свитче все порты в 1-ом в-лане. DHCP будер раздавать адреса как Вы его настроите. Свитч level 3 поможет с маршрутизацией. Ну как то так.

Answer (score 0):

Все отделы поскаешь в разные ВЛАН, в общем как ты и описал.Сводишь все ВЛАНы к одному комутатору, в него втыкаешь dhcp сервер, на данном сервере запрещаешь через iptables проход пакетов с ВЛАНа в другие ВЛАНы.Вот и все.